# How do I tackle insulating rim joists with brick in a partially finished basement

Tags: insulation, basement, energy-efficiency

I have done a fair bit of research on this, but still left with a dilemma. Here's some basics:

- 1920s single level, brick built home (see photos linked below). Exterior brick is painted.
- located in zone 5. Northern Nevada desert mountain climate. Dry and hot summers, some rain, winters we get some snow but moderately dry overall.
- basement has two sections-- the dug out portion is mostly finished, and there's a crawl space connected to it which is not finished.  The crawl space is about 30% of the full house layout, and the dugout/finished basement is about 70%
- I cannot get behind the walls to the finished space to do more insulation, but I am considering insulating the rim joists in the crawl space to help condition that space better (it has forced air heat ducts running through it).  The crawl also gets secondary heat from the finished space via an access door (finished space has two air registers)

Here's my challenge...I have learned that shooting closed cell foam onto the exposed brick rim joists is a bad idea because that can prevent the brick from releasing moisture. I am considering just caulking/foam sealing the joining edges around each joist, and putting rockwool in front for some insulation, but I have also heard that rockwool can cause issues with moisture.

Given that I cannot access the rim joists in the finished sections of the basement, and there is an opening to the crawl space which cannot be sealed off at this point, is it even worth tackling the rim joists in the crawl space?  I don't want to risk creating more moisture damage if the juice isn't worth the squeeze.

Thank you so much!

Pics:
Links to the photos:
Exterior:
https://pasteboard.co/npVuaRrRGXuj.jpg
Rim joist
https://pasteboard.co/5845emTFkzaw.jpg
Walls in the crawl area (rim joist hidden behind ductwork)
https://pasteboard.co/nDesq0yymccR.jpg

Comment: A picture or two would help in understanding your problem.

Comment: Images are not found today...